# Getting information from database to be displayed on projects

Tags: java, database, netbeans, project

Im trying to get information in sql from database, there are two entries in each column but and with the following code, i am able to get the first entry information, if i wanted to get the second entry's records and display it also in project how would i get it?

```
    String username1= rs.getString ("USERNAME");
    String password1= rs.getString ("PASSWORD");
    String aname1= rs.getString ("a_name");
    String aname2= rs.getString ("a_name");

    System.out.print("Enter Your Username: ");
    String usernamea=(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("Enter Your Password: ");
    String passworda=(br.readLine());
    if ((usernamea.equals(username1) && (passworda.equals(password1))))
    {
        System.out.println("Login Success! Welcome "+aname1+"!");
        System.out.println("You are granted with Admin Acess!");
        rs.close();
    }
    else if ((usernamea.equals(username2) && (passworda.equals(password2))))
    {
        System.out.println("Login Success! Welcome Guest User!");
        rs.close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear with what you want? By entries, are you talking attributes or records?

Comment: Records please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, nor am I sure how the code you posted actually relates to what you are asking.

When you say "you want the 2nd entry", I am assuming you mean the 2nd record in the SQL table.

```
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)){

Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]");

rs.next();

//All data stored in the ResultSet obj, to which you may loop through & select rows of interest. Particularly useful methods are .getMetaData(), .getRow(), etc.

}
```

Hopefully this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a ResultSet rs, you can call rs.next(). For Example some Code:

```
            if (rs.next())
        {
            s.name = rs.getString(1);
            s.creator = rs.getString(2);
            s.dbname = rs.getString(3);
            s.tsname = rs.getString(4);
            s.cardf = rs.getFloat(5);
            s.npages = rs.getInt(6);
            s.statstime = rs.getString(7);
            s.avgrowlen = rs.getInt(8);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code:

```
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]");
    String username1 = rs.getString ("USERNAME");
    String password1 = rs.getString ("PASSWORD");
    String aname1 = rs.getString ("a_name");

    rs.next();

    String username2 = rs.getString ("USERNAME");
    String password2 = rs.getString ("PASSWORD");
    String aname2 = rs.getString ("a_name");
```

Now you can check both the first entry and the second.

Nevertheless, the better practice is to create a user object, save `username`, `password` and `aname` in it.
Then, using some loop, you can go through the entire result set and get all the information from it.

```
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]");

    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    while(rs.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(rs.getString ("USERNAME"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString ("PASSWORD"));
            user.setAname(rs.getString ("a_name"));
            userList.add(user);
    }
```